# When runing cucumber from main method giving me skeleton of my features

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

When running the cucumber test runner from main class as per below screenshot just giving me the skeleton of the feature to define the steps. Whereas I have already written the code to achieve the steps.

Attaching screenshot to understand my code as well project structure. 
`Mainjarvish.java` is the main file from where I am trying to run the `TestRunner.java`.

[image: main method]

Comment: The glue option takes a package path. I guess removing `src/test/java/` from it would solve it.

Comment: I added as -g = "stepDefinations" still it didn't work. @SubOptimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because your class `test/java/stepDefinitions/Contacts` is not in the same class path scope as `src/main/java/MainJarvish`.

Assume following structure.

```
src/main/java/MainJarvish.java
src/test/java/stepDefinitions/Contacts.java
src/test/java/FeatureList/Smoke.feature
```

**MainJarvish.java**

```
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;

public class MainJarvish {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] options = {"--glue", "stepDefinitions",
            "src/test/java/FeatureList/Smoke.feature"};
        byte exitcode = Main.run(options, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        System.out.println("exitcode = " + exitcode);
    }
}
```

**Contacts.java**

```
package stepDefinitions;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class Contacts {
    @Given("^Submit message for execution$")
    public void submitMessageForExecution() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("submitMessageForExecution");
    }
}
```

**Smoke.feature**

```
Feature: example feature

  Scenario: describe the test scenario
    Given Submit message for execution
```

compile the classes

```
mvn clean compile test-compile
```

it generates the `class` files

```
target/classes/MainJarvish.class
target/test-classes/stepDefinitions/Contacts.class
```

When you now execute `ManJarvish`

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=MainJarvish
```

the class `Contacts` is not on the class path and therefor the step definition is not found.

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli)
...
Undefined scenarios:
src/test/java/FeatureList/Smoke.feature:3 # describe the test scenario

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
1 Steps (1 undefined)
```

As `MainJarvish` is located in `src/java` at its execution only the project classes below `target/classes` are added to the class path.

If the class `Contacts` would be on the class path, e.g. by changing the class path scope

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=MainJarvish -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

now are the classes below `target/classes` and below `target/test-classes` added to the class path and the step definition is found.

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli)
submitMessageForExecution
...    
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
1 Steps (1 passed)
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you might consider to move `MainJarvish` to `test/java` or create a test runner class.

**src/test/java/TestRunner.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "stepDefinitions",
        features="src/test/java/FeatureList/Smoke.feature"
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

then you can run your feature test as

```
mvn clean test
```

output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestRunner
submitMessageForExecution

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
1 Steps (1 passed)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for your help. I really I appreciate it.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for your help. I really I appreciate it. When I moved the `mainjarvish` to test/java/ it worked. But my main intention to create the main jarivish to have a main file in (main/java) and set the manifest in build.gradle and create a jar file with all the dependency zipped into it. Is it possible or I am being very much wishful?

Comment: @SobhitSharma You could change the scope of the Cucumber dependencies from `test` to `compile` (the default one) and move all files from `src/test/java/` to `src/main/java/`. You would need to amend the path for the feature files, as they would be different inside the jar file.